# Comparing the Product and Standard Topologies on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

I am asked to compare the product topology on $\mathbb{R}_d \times \mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{R}_d$ denotes the discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$?, with the standard topology on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, whose basic elements are rectangles in the plane. Let $T_p$ denote the product topology on $\mathbb{R}_d \times \mathbb{R}$, and $T_s$ the standard topology on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$

Showing that $T_S \subseteq T_p$ is easy enough: the basis elements of $T_s$ are rectangles, and clearly I can find a vertical line segment, which are the basis elements of $T_p$, inside the rectangle which contains a given element $x$ in the rectangle. Of course, I did a more rigorous argument to show this.

Now I am trying to show that $T_p \not\subseteq T_s$. This is intuitively obvious: a rectangle cannot be contained in a vertical line segment. However, I am having trouble showing this rigorously. What I am trying to do is take the basis element $\{x\} \times (0,1)$ of $T_p$ and show that it contains no basis element of $T_s$, but everything I have tried has been unsucessful.

Here is one attempt. By way of contradiction, suppose $T_p \subseteq T_p$. Then there exists a basis element $(a,b) \times (c,d)$ of $T_s$ such that $(a,b) \times (c,d) \subseteq \{0\} \times (0,1)$. I took the point $(b- \epsilon, d - \epsilon) \in (a,b) \times (c,d)$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, but I couldn't get any contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If $(a,b)\times (c,d)\subseteq \{0\}\times(0,1)$ (with $a<b$, $c<d$) then in particular $(\frac{a+b}2,\frac{c+d}2)\in\{0\}\times(0,1)$, i.e., $\frac{a+b}2=0$. But also $(\frac{a+2b}3,\frac{c+d}2)\in\{0\}\times(0,1)$, i.e., $\frac {a+2b}3=0$. Both together imply $a=b=0$, contradicting $a<b$.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest is to note that $I=\{x\}\times (c,d)$ is open in $T_p$ but not in $T_s$ because it does not contain any open rectangle. If $(x,y)\in I$ there is no open rectangle (for $T_s$) containing $(x,y)$ which is contained in $I$.